# MySQL Database disconnecting randomly from PHP application

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp

We are facing an issue in which the Mysql connection disconnects or gets timeout randomly from the PHP application.

We have 3 PHP applications on 2 different servers all of these are having this issue

Application details:

- 1 application is built up in PHP 5.6 (CakePHP) and 2 are in PHP 7.2(CakePHP).
- Nginx server with FreeBSD.
- 1 application uses Mysql 5.7 and the other 2 applications use Mysql 8.

Error details:

```
Error: [PDOException] SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Operation timed out

Error: [MissingConnectionException] Database connection "Mysql" is missing, or could not be created.
Exception Attributes: array (
'class' => 'Mysql',
'message' => 'SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Operation now in progress',
'enabled' => true,
)
```

[image]

This issue is not occurring on any specific action or query, randomly it happens even without any load to the application.

Comment: Have you resolved your issue? If not, are all your 3 running CakePHP applications of different PHP and MySQL versions have similar code? Or are they each entirely different projects?